# Docker --> python+Postgress running successfully in the Docekr images - but NOT ABLE to hit the url for my APIs from my local pc from postman or CURL

Tags: python-3.x, docker-compose, dockerfile, containers, port

**My Docker File is**

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM python:3.7.2
RUN mkdir my_app
COPY . my_app
WORKDIR /my_app
ARG DB_URL=postgresql://postgres:postgres@my_app_db:5432/appdb
ARG KEY=abcdfg1
ENV DATABASE_URL=$DB_URL
EXPOSE 8080:8080
EXPOSE 5432:5432
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
WORKDIR /my_app/app
RUN python manage.py db init
CMD ["python", "my_app.py" ]
```

**My Docker-composer.yml is**

```
version: '3'
 services:
  postgres_db:
    image: postgres:11.1
    container_name: my_app_db
    ports:
     - 5432:5432
    restart: always
    environment:
     POSTGRES_USER: postgres
     POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
     POSTGRES_DB: appdb
    volumes:
     - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
  app_api:
   build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
   container_name: my_app
   ports:
     - 8080:8080
   volumes:
     - ./:/app
   depends_on:
     - postgres_db
volumes:
  pgdata:
```

The Flask **my_app.py**:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
create_app(app).run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

i Run the commands below:

1. `docker login`
2. `docker-compose up -d`

2 containers Running

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                              COMMAND                  CREATED       STATUS       PORTS                              NAMES
f495fd1f7b38   my_project_my_app                  "python my_app.py…"      3 hours ago   Up 3 hours   5432/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   my_app
2ae314034656   postgres:11.1                      "docker-entrypoint.s…"   3 hours ago   Up 3 hours   0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp             my_app_db
```

I can see the terminal of the bash of **my_app** running as below:

```
Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
Restarting with stat
Debugger is active!
Debugger PIN: 602-498-436
```

I can run Curl in that terminal (via Docker exec -it my_app bash ) and succesfully call my apis in the app and get responses. THe app and the db container are communicating succesfully.

If try to run my app from postman on my pc and hit the below urls:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/myapp/api/v1/endpoint/1

http://localhost:8080/myapp/api/v1/endpoint/1
```

nothing happens!!!

OS: **Windonws 10**

**1. How could i call my apis from my postman or local machine?**

The problem seems to be from my pc to the my_app on local Docker

Comment: I'd advise to (re)read [ask], make sure your code is a [mre] and ask *one specific* question.

Comment: changed the question and simplified on how could i hit the URl of my app(api) via local machine - its a simple question and detials are more than minmal

Answer (score 0):

well, the actual question is how do you run your docker engine. With LinuxVM inside Hyper-V?

Are you using Docker Desktop?

The answer to that would be, to find out on what IP is your VM running/listening on and then you can call your API with:

```
http://yourVMIP:8080/myapp/api/v1/endpoint/1
```

And it will probably work. I know I had to find out my Hyper-V Linux IP to link it up for a test drive.

### Fix for this case

In this case the actual issue was the port Dockerfile was exposing and compose was going on the port 8080, but the flask application was running and binding itself on the default port of 5000.

Solution was:
In your docker-compose file you need to adjust the ports to:

```
ports:
    - 8080:5000
```

and it will connect to the rights ports on host and right one inside the application

Comment: Yep, I’m using docker desktop on windows 10. Where do i run hyper-V, on windows ?

Comment: Under docker desktop settings > General, you can see if you use WSL2 based engine or if you are using Hyper-V Backend.

Comment: And i have just lunched a random nginx:latest container mapping the -p 80:80 and checked the UI inside DD (NOTE: I am running WSL2 engine rn as you should). And DD offers you a button which lets u open the port/page inside browser, it could autoprepare your call you need (localhost, IP, what docker desktop is currently configured as using). (reference: https://prnt.sc/aGpId3sovNjl)

Comment: I had the wsl2 disabled. Shall I enable it?

Comment: @Franco you should. But your host needs to have WSL2 enabled and configured beforehand. Before doing anything I do recommend going through a tutorial and check it out (for instance: https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/how-to-install-wsl2-on-windows-10)

Comment: I need to install it. Yep. I will do it. Once installed I shall simply call the localhost:8080? Or still find out the ip?

Comment: I am using WSL2 and I can freely reference to localhost

Comment: I just noticed @Franco your app says: "Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)", and you are binding it to port 8080. You need to do one of two things aswell.

Change the port which application is running/listening traffic at to 8080 from 5000.

Or 

You need to adjust expose to 5000 and then in ports section bind 8080 from host to 5000 of application.

Im sorry I missed this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244166/discussion-between-franco-and-matic-strajnsak).

Comment: You mean Port: -8080:500 or 5000:8080 in both docker compose and dockerfile ?

Comment: No problem, glad I could help you.

Answer (score 0):

In the end  - i did not know about the WSL2 features- once that was enabled  i have re-instaleed Docker Desktop - configure WSL version 2 and install Ubuntu terminal for windowns.

```
DB
 ports:
     - 5433:5432

APP
  ports:
        - 5001:5000
```

I called the http://locahost:5001/myapp/api and it worked.